# dreamweaver how to change background color to black

Tags: dreamweaver

dreamweaver how to change background color to black?

Ctrl + U open preference, choose coding color, select black, 
however, all text are invisible, you need to change all text to light color and how?

Answer (score 0):

to change all text to light color, you need to replace Colors.xml

to find it,

For Windows 7 & 8:

OS hard drive > Users > [yourusername] > AppData > Roaming > Adobe > Dreamweaver > en_US > Configuration > CodeColoring.

replace the content with:

```
<codeColors>
<colorGroup>
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLEntity" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptNative" text="#009999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptNumber" text="#FF0000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptClient" text="#990099" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptSpryKeywords" text="#FF6208" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptSpryClasses" text="#FF6208" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_TemplateText" text="#999999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_TemplateCommentText" text="#006600" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_TemplateCommentAttr" text="#006600" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CFCommentText" text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFF99" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavaJSP" text="#009999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavaImplicit" text="#999900" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavaOther" text="#990099" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JSPPageOperator" text="#000000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JSPTaglibOperator" text="#000000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JSPIncludeOperator" text="#000000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptBlock" text="#FF0000" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptComment" text="#FF9900" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptConstant" text="#552200" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptString" text="#CC0000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptFunctionsKeywords" text="#0000FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptReserved" text="#006600" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptTypes" text="#009999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptVariables" text="#0066FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASPIncludeAttributes" text="#990099" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASPDirOperator" text="#000000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_LibraryText" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_DateText" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASPJSNative" text="#009999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASPJSKeywords" text="#990099" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASPNetCSharpKeywords" text="#990099" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_VBSNative" text="#990099" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_VBSConstants" text="#009999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_VBNetNative" text="#990099" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_VBNetConstants" text="#009999" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLAnchor" text="#006600" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLForm" text="#FF9900" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLImage" text="#990099" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLObject" text="#990000" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLScript" text="#990000" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLStyle" text="#990099" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLTable" text="#009999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_SpryAttributes" text="#FF6208" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_Spry_Tag_Normal" bgcolor="#F8DOAF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_Spry_Tag_Hover" bgcolor="#FF9B58" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_Spry_Tag_Selected" bgcolor="#FF6D0C" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLComment" text="#999999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLString" text="#0000FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLNumber" text="#0000FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptFunction" text="#000000" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptBracket" text="#000099" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptReserved" text="#000099" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptString" text="#0000FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptComment" text="#999999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSSelector" text="#FF00FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSProperty" text="#000099" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSValue" text="#0000FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSImport" text="#009999" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSMedia" text="#990000" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CssKeywordImportant" text="#FF0000" bold="true" />
    <tagColor id="DWTagLibrary_cfc" text="#990033" />
    <tagColor id="DWTagLibrary_cfml" text="#990033" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASPDirTagKeywords" text="#990033" />
    <tagColor id="DWTagLibrary_aspnetmmtags" text="#990033" />
    <tagColor id="DWTagLibrary_aspnettemplates" text="#990033" />
    <tagColor id="DWTagLibrary_aspnet" text="#990033" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_CFScriptTag" text="#990033" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASPDirString" text="#0000FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ActionscriptProperty" text="#000084" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ActionscriptNative" text="#000084" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ActionscriptNumber" text="#000000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ActionscriptFunction" text="#000084" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ActionscriptBracket" text="#000000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ActionscriptOperator" text="#000000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ActionscriptReserved" text="#000084" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ActionscriptString" text="#0000FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ActionscriptComment" text="#848284" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ActionscriptRemoting" text="#000084" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASCommBracket" text="#000099" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASCommComment" text="#999999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASCommFunction" text="#000000" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASCommNative" text="#009999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASCommNumber" text="#FF0000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASCommReserved" text="#000099" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASCommString" text="#0000FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASRemoteBracket" text="#000099" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASRemoteComment" text="#999999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASRemoteFunction" text="#000000" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASRemoteNative" text="#009999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASRemoteNumber" text="#FF0000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASRemoteReserved" text="#000099" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASRemoteString" text="#0000FF" />
</colorGroup>
<colorGroup doctypes="PHP_MySQL">
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_CFScriptTag" text="#990033" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSImport" text="#009999" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSMedia" text="#990000" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSComment" text="#999999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CssKeywordImportant" text="#E77E7E" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSProperty" text="#FFCC00" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSSelector" text="#33CCFF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSString" text="#FFCC33" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSValue" text="#99FF33" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_DateText" text="#333333" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLAnchor" text="#99FF00" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLString" text="#0099FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLComment" text="#666666" bgcolor="#000033" italic="true" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLForm" text="#FFCC00" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLImage" text="#9966FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLNumber" text="#3399FF" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLObject" text="#FF3333" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLTag" text="#00FFFF" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLScript" text="#993333" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLEntity" text="#FFFFFF" bold="true" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLStyle" text="#FFCCFF" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLTable" text="#00CCCC" />
    <tagColor id="DWTagLibrary_html" text="#E3DE5F" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLText" text="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#000033" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptBracket" text="#33CCFF" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptClient" text="#9966CC" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptComment" text="#CCCCCC" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavaScriptDefaultText" text="#FFFFFF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptFunction" text="#CCCCCC" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptIdentifier" text="#FFFFFF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptNative" text="#00FFFF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptNumber" text="#FF3366" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptOperator" text="#0099FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptRegexp" text="#99FF00" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptReserved" text="#0099FF" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptString" text="#0099FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_LibraryText" text="#666666" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptBlock" text="#E77E7E" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptBracket" text="#CC9900" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptComment" text="#FFCC00" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptConstant" text="#FF3333" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PhpScriptDefaultText" text="#CCCCCC" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptFunction" text="#0099FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptFunctionsKeywords" text="#7CB7F1" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptIdentifier" text="#DEDECB" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptNumber" text="#8FE28F" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptOperator" text="#DEDECB" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptReserved" text="#8FE28F" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptString" text="#FF6666" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptTypes" text="#00CCCC" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_PHPScriptVariables" text="#66FFFF" />
    <tagColor id="DWTagLibrary_php" text="#0099FF" />
</colorGroup>
<colorGroup doctypes="HTML">
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASPIncludeString" text="#9C0" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_ASPIncludeAttributes" text="#96F" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_AspIncludeDirDefaultText" text="#666" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_CFScriptTag" text="#F33" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSImport" text="#9C0" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSMedia" text="#F30" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSComment" text="#999" bgcolor="#252A32" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CssKeywordImportant" text="#F00" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSProperty" text="#09F" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSSelector" text="#F9F" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSString" text="#FC3" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSValue" text="#9F3" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_DateText" text="#000" bgcolor="#FFC" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLAnchor" text="#9F0" underline="false" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLString" text="#999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLComment" text="#666" bgcolor="#252A32" italic="true" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLForm" text="#FC0" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLImage" text="#96F" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLNumber" text="#39F" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLObject" text="#F33" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLTag" text="#0FF" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLScript" text="#933" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLEntity" text="#FFF" bold="true" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLStyle" text="#FCF" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLTable" text="#0CC" />
    <tagColor id="DWTagLibrary_html" text="#E3DE5F" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_HTMLText" text="#FFF" bgcolor="#252A32" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptBracket" text="#3FC" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptClient" text="#96C" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptComment" text="#999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavaScriptDefaultText" text="#FFF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptFunction" text="#999" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptIdentifier" text="#F30" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptNative" text="#0CC" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptNumber" text="#F36" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptOperator" text="#09F" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptRegexp" text="#9F0" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptReserved" text="#0FF" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptString" text="#39F" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_LibraryText" text="#FFF" bgcolor="#FFC" />
    <tagColor id="DWTagLibrary_templates" text="#06C" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_SVGString" text="#060" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_SVGAttr" text="#009" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_SVGComment" text="#999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_SVGNumber" text="#F00" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_SVGTagGroup" text="#009" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_SVGTag" text="#009" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_SVGText" text="#000" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_TemplateCommentText" text="#060" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_TemplateCommentAttr" text="#060" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_TemplateText" text="#999" />
</colorGroup>
<colorGroup doctypes="JavaScript">
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptBracket" text="#00FFFF" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptClient" text="#9966CC" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptComment" text="#999999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavaScriptDefaultText" text="#FFFFFF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptFunction" text="#99FF33" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptIdentifier" text="#999999" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptNative" text="#FF99FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptNumber" text="#FF3300" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptOperator" text="#FFFF00" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptRegexp" text="#CCCC00" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptReserved" text="#CCCC00" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_JavascriptString" text="#FF9900" />
</colorGroup>
<colorGroup doctypes="CSS">
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSImport" text="#9C0" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSMedia" text="#E77E7E" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSComment" text="#666" bgcolor="#252A32" italic="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CssKeywordImportant" text="#E77E7E" bold="true" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSProperty" text="#FC0" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSSelector" text="#3CF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSString" text="#FC3" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_CSSValue" text="#9F3" />
</colorGroup>
<colorGroup doctypes="XML">
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_CFScriptTag" text="#993366" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLAnchor" text="#99FF33" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLForm" text="#FFCC33" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLImage" text="#9966CC" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLObject" text="#CC6699" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLScript" text="#CC3366" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLStyle" text="#9966CC" />
    <tagColor id="CodeColor_HTMLTable" text="#00CCFF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_XMLString" text="#99FF33" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_XMLComment" text="#666666" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_XMLNumber" text="#FF3333" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_XMLTag" text="#0099FF" />
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_XMLText" text="#FFFFFF" />
</colorGroup>
<colorGroup doctypes="Text">
    <syntaxColor id="CodeColor_TextText" text="#0CF" />
</colorGroup>
```